# Good coding Practices, ELSE IF

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a lot of ELSE IF statemets but I would like to ask if there is a better way to code, here is my code.

```
        if (txtMyTime.Text == "00:00")
        {
            myInteger = 0;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "00:30")
        {
            myInteger = 0.5;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "01:00")
        {
            myInteger = 1;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "01:30")
        {
            myInteger = 1.5;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "02:00")
        {
            myInteger = 2;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "02:30")
        {
            myInteger = 2.5;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "03:00")
        {
            myInteger = 3;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "03:30")
        {
            myInteger = 3.5;
        }
        else if (txtMyTime.Text == "04:00")
        {
            myInteger = 4;
        }
        // And so on, until txtMyTime.Text == "24:00"
```

Can some SO guru tell me if there is a better way of coding? It would be awesome for a newbie like me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: `int` can't be `.5` - `myInteger = 0.5;`

Comment: I'm sorry is a double

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `TimeSpan` class to manage this for you. This also recognizes `04:15` as `4.25` for example.

```
string txtMyTime = "04:30";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(txtMyTime);
double result = ts.TotalHours; //4.5
```

in one line:

```
myDouble = TimeSpan.Parse(txtMyTime.Text).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a large sequence of if-else or a switch block. `myInteger` is not created arbitrary from your string. So you split it by the colon, convert the first part to int and check the second part in order to know if you have to add 0.5:

```
string[] parts = txtMyTime.Text.Split(':');
myInteger = int.Parse(parts[0]) + (parts[1] == "30" ? 0.5 : 0);
```